# remove all special characters between : and first alphabet

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write a perl script to remove all special characters and spaces between : and first alphabet

```
$53:$? Abc
```

should yeild

```
$53:Abc
```

can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: Put out some effort and try something, post it here, then we'll help you correct it.

Comment: what are "special characters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use look behind/ahead to match the start/end and a reluctant quantifier between:

```
$var =~ s/(?<=:).*?(?=[a-zA-Z])//
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Assuming `$str = "$53:$? Abc";` and `$pattern` has the correct pattern that will return everything between a colon and a letter.

```
my $newStr = "";
if($str =~ $pattern)
{
    $newStr = $`; //add the text to the left of the match
    //loop through each character of $& (what the regex matched) and remove it
    //from the string if it is a special character then do the below
    $newStr += $&; //add the matching text without the special characters
    $newStr += $'; //add the text to the right of the match
}
```

I'm fairly new at regex so I couldn't come up with the correct matching pattern, but I figured this should at least help you get started since it seems like you don't even have a starting point. However, there may be an "easier/better" way using only regex but this is how I would go about this problem.